# The value of attribute "SKU" must be unique

Tags: magento-1.9

When trying to create a product, the error "The value of attribute "SKU" must be unique" shows, but there is no product with this SKU on the products list.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: What is the SKU you are trying to insert? Try adding a number or letter after the SKU and see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem and was stumped for a while on it. The only way I was able to correct it (without directly editing the database) was to find the sku ID in the `catalog_product_entity` table and manually enter it into Magento admin.

I used phpMyAdmin, found the `catalog_product_entity` table, and then located the sku Magento told me already existed. There will be a column in the table called `id` - make a note of this number for the sku in question.

In Magento admin panel, go to Catalog > Manage Products - and click any product as if you were editing it. In the url on the product edit page find the section that says `/id/`. The number directly after this is the id of the sku you are editing. Change this to the id you found in the database table and reload the page. It should open to the product that was previously not visible in admin. From here you can delete the sku and go save the product you initially wanted to create.

Answer (score 2):

There might be SKU which is deleted but still in to the database you need to index management and try again !!

You can find the sku in the catalog_product_entity table or any of this catalog_product_%.

Comment: Yes indeed. The sku is in catalog_product_entity table. Should I delete this row from the table?

Comment: I've performed insertion of one product by REST API: the product is saved but I give an error:
`{
  "messages": {
    "error": [
      {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid attribute \"sku\": The value of attribute \"SKU\" must be unique"
      }
    ]
  }
}`
I can't understand where is the problem! :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can run SQL query directly from database manager system (ie: phpMyAdmin), you can check if duplicate sku is present in `catalog_product_entity` table with a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), sku
FROM `catalog_product_entity`
GROUP BY sku HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you got results, follow [this way](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96337/24845) to remove duplicate sku.