# Deleting dupicate skus with added conditions in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

I am trying to delete duplicate skus in magento.

I can confirm with this query that duplicates exist on the db.

```
SELECT `entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` GROUP BY `sku` HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

However, from these duplicates that are returned; I want to delete a product that has ***no image***, ***product name is ALL CAPS***, and ***no brand***.

to narrow it down even further as the above conditions can exist on both skus, I don't want to remove both so I want to use the ***created_at*** field and delete the one that is older.

This is tricky, I hope it is clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[How to remove a duplicate sku via database?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86170/how-to-remove-a-duplicate-sku-via-database)

this might help you. Extend the Select with whatever you need. To select only uppercase use 
`WHERE name REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$';`